# Inheritance same methods implementation

Tags: c#, oop, interface

I have the following code. (in c#) 
interface 1:

```
public interface iBclass
{
   int addition(int a);

   int s(); //and more methods from this ......


}
```

interface 2:

```
 public interface iAclass
 {
    int addition(int a);
    //more methods.....
 }
```

Class that inherits both interfaces:

```
public class dClass : iAclass , iBclass
{

    int iAclass.addition(int a)
    {
        return 0;
    }

   int iBclass.addition(int a)
    {
        return 1;
    }


   public int s()
   {
       return 3;
   }
}
```

the problem is i am not able to access the Method `iAclass.addition(int a)` and `iBclass.addition(int a)` with the d object.

```
  dClass d = new dClass();
```

how can i access those method by 'd' object? and why those interface methods are not allow to define as public?

Comment: looks like you don't really need IAclass

Comment: @markg : my IAclass having extra functions that are not present in the IBclass then?

Comment: By default it is private right?

Comment: @ssilas777: yes.i need return type. void allows the public declaration. but if you add some return type to it then public is not allowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The interfaces are implemented explicitly. So you can only call them by using the interface:

```
dClass d = new dClass();
iAclass a = (iAclass)d;
a.addition(123);  // Calls implementation for iAclass
iBclass b = (iBclass)d;
b.addition(123);  // Calls implementation for iBclass
```

See this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx) for details.